# Is the equality of Bloom filters analogous to set equivalence?

Tags: sets, streaming-algorithm, equality, bloom-filters

- I have two multisets $A$, $B$ where $A \subseteq B$.
- Using these two sets, we construct two  [Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) $BF(A), BF(B)$; both using bitsets of size $n$ with the same $k$ hash functions.

What's the probability that:

$A \not\equiv B$ but $BF(A) = BF(B)$

**Notes:**

- Since $A$ and $B$ are multisets, they might have duplicate elements.
- However, duplications should not affect set equaivalence or subset relation. Due to lack of notation (on my side) please assume deduplication when checking for subsets or equivalence.
- By Bloom filter equality, I mean the bitsets being equal.
- I think we could assume hash functions are random and are independent of the elements of the sets.
- If needed, [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) (ratio of intersection over union as an indicator of set similarity) could be approximated as
  $J(A,B) = \frac{|A|}{|B|}$ (or via [MinHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash))

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you analyze any special case?  For instance, if $|A|=|B|=1$, can you figure out the answer?  What if $|A|=1$ but $B$ is arbitrary?  Do you want an exact answer even if the formula is a complex sum, or do you want an approximate answer that shows the asymptotics, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find an upper bound on the probability of a collision in the fingerprint.  Suppose the Bloom filter uses $k$ hash functions and maps into a bit array of size $m$.

---

The case $k=1$ is much easier to analyze explicitly, so I'll start with that case.

If $A\ne B$, there must be some element that is in $A$ but not $B$, let's say $a$.  $a$ must hash to some bit of the array.  With probability $(1-1/m)^{|B|}$, none of the elements of $B$ map to this bit position, and in this case, we necessarily have $BF(A)\ne BF(B)$.

So, if $A \ne B$, the probability that $BF(A)=BF(B)$ is at most $1 - (1-1/m)^{|B|}$.  When $|B|$ is small compared to $m$, this is roughly $|B|/m$.

---

The calculations get messier when $k>1$.  If you're satisfied with an approximate upper bound, you can use the fact that when $k \ll \sqrt{m}$, $a$ will typically hash to $k$ different bits ($k$ different positions in the array).  The probability that at least one of the elements of $B$ maps to a particular bit is roughly $|B|k/m$, assuming $|B| \ll m/k$ (following similar reasoning to that above).  So, the probability that all of those $k$ bits are mapped to by some element of $B$ is roughly $(|B|k/m)^k$.

So, if $A \ne B$, the probability that $BF(A)=BF(B)$ is at most about $(|B|k/m)^k$, under the conditions that $|B| \ll m/k$ and $k \ll \sqrt{m}$.

Comment: Thank you this gives me enough direction of thought to address the cases where $k > 1$.